# struts 2 collection type conversion problem

Tags: types, struts2, type-conversion

I've trouble using type conversion in struts 2 to convert collection of bean. 
I've following action class :

```
@Validation()
@Conversion()
public class HelloWorldAction extends ActionSupport {


    private List<HelloBean> helloBeans = new ArrayList<HelloBean>();


    public String execute() throws Exception {
        System.out.println(helloBeans);
        return SUCCESS;
    }
    public List<HelloBean> getHelloBeans() {
        return helloBeans;
    }

     @TypeConversion(rule = ConversionRule.COLLECTION, converter = "foo.HelloBean")
    public void setHelloBeans(List<HelloBean> helloBeans) {
        this.helloBeans = helloBeans;
    }

}
```

and my bean class :

```
public class HelloBean {
    private String name;
    private Integer age;
    public String getName() {
        return name;
    }
    public void setName(String name) {
        this.name = name;
    }
    public Integer getAge() {
        return age;
    }
    public void setAge(Integer age) {
        this.age = age;
    }

}
```

and my JSP file :

```
<s:form action="helloWorld">

    <s:textfield name="helloBeans.name" label="name1"/>
    <s:textfield name="helloBeans.name" label="name2" />
    <s:textfield name="helloBeans.age" label="age1"/>
    <s:textfield name="helloBeans.age" label="age2"/>
        <s:submit />
    </s:form>
```

When process has been submitted, struts always give me 4 object, instead of 2 object inside collection. I know other workaround using index in property will solve problem, but for my case i need collection to be dynamic. Is there way to solve this kind of issue ?

I've tried others annotation as well :

```
@Element(value =foo.HelloBean.class )
    @CreateIfNull( value = true )
    @KeyProperty( value = "name" )
    private List<HelloBean> helloBeans = new ArrayList<HelloBean>();
```

but none of these worked

Comment: FYI: You don't need to initialize helloBeans in your action. Your setter will do that.

Answer (score 0):

AFAIK you must use:

```
    <s:form action="hello-world">
        <s:textfield name="helloBeans[1].name" label="name1"/>
        <s:textfield name="helloBeans[1].age" label="age1"/>
        <s:textfield name="helloBeans[2].name" label="name2" />
        <s:textfield name="helloBeans[2].age" label="age2"/>
        <s:submit />
    </s:form>
```

I think the biggest issue is not that it must be done this way but that you think that this means it can not be dynamic, consider that the text fields are rendered more-less (actually less because I removed the 'id' and 'value' attributes):

```
<input type="text" name="helloBeans[1].name"/>
<input type="text" name="helloBeans[1].age"/>
...
```

There is no reason you simply can not either handle this in your jsp dynamically as done to test the view:

```
    <h1>Display HelloBeans</h1>
    <table>
        <s:iterator value="helloBeans">
            <tr>
                <td><s:property value="name"/></td>
                <td><s:property value="age"/></td>
            </tr>
        </s:iterator>
    </table>
```

Or if your issue is client side then use JavaScript (or better a JS library such as jQuery) to add new text fields to the DOM... and use string concatenation to build the correct OGNL for the 'name' attributes.

Note if your dynamic behavior is server side in the JSP then

```
<s:property value="#helloBeans.index" />
```

will get you the index of the current iteration when used inside the s:iterator tag.